# Redirect List Links from inside a page viewer web part

Tags: 2010, list-view, page-viewer-web-part

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site collection, and i am seeking to enable a couple of the sub sites to view some list information from the parent site on their main web part page.  The info is coming from a heavily modified Issue Tracking List on the root site.

I want a small window on the main page of the sub-sites showing recent updates to the Issues.  I am doing this by creating a basic .aspx page on the parent site with only a boxed list view Title, Summary, Last Updated.

It looks great, but when you click on the link to view the full issue, it stays inside the page viewer.  Is there any way to have the target of the list link go to either a new tab/page, or a different page entirely?

Alternatively if there is a better way to do this I would entertain any and all options.  I have messed around a bit with SOAP Service Connection to possibly create a list directly on the child site, but seems quite cumbersome especially to make the displayed data look good.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: 2010/2013/?? Don't know that it really matters, but might.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have specified Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: I take it you want the item to appear in the popup "window" which appears with the grayed out background? If so, the problem is it's not reading the master page from the page viewer. You need to add a code snippet within the page viewer to allow it to work. I have an example at work and my memory is short as to what exactly to put into the code snippet, but I believe that's your problem. I've ran into the same exact thing before.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Pageviewer Web Part I have simply changed the link's target to accomplish this:

```
<a href="www.somelink" target="_parent">
```

You can also use:

"_blank" to open a new tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

This code in a JavaScript Function

```
window.open("http://www.somelink.com", "_parent");
```

worked for us.